# Can secret hats get a description on the leaderboard as well?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2020

On the leaderboard there is a description in a tooltip when you hover over a regular hat, like so:

[image: Screenshot of the leaderboard page showing the tooltip on hover of the Doorman hat: "Doorman - 3 successful reopen vote reviews"]

When you hover over a secret hat you see this:

[image: Screenshot of the leaderboard page showing the tooltip on hover of the Vexillologist hat: "Vexillologist"]

On the winterbash homepage there is a bit more elaborate description, namely: 
[image: Screenshot of the Vexillologist badge on the winterbash homepage showing "Secret" as subtitle]

Can we add this "Secret" to the tooltip on the leaderboard page like this:

> Vexillologist - Secret

Comment: I suspect Vexillologist being a **terrible** pun (my favorites ones) for raising a flag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Done

> earned a secret hat
> AND made it to leaderboard
> tooltip amended

Comment: I am very curious about this haiku!